# Import Excel Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I'm facing an issue when import data with the excel laravel package.
Eg: In my import file have 5 items with 3 item error after use validation I want to skip there items and continue import 2 items remain. currently if in the file have any error it will stop import process.
Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you might want to skip all errors, e.g. duplicate database records. By using the `SkipsOnError` concern, you get control over what happens the moment a model import fails. When using `SkipsOnError` the entire import will not be `rollbacked` when an database exception occurs.

```
   <?php
    
    namespace App\Imports;
    
    use App\User;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnError;
    use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
    
    class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, SkipsOnError
    {
        use Importable;
    
        /**
         * @param \Throwable $e
         */
        public function onError(\Throwable $e)
        {
            // Handle the exception how you'd like.
        }
    }
```

If you automatically want to skip all exceptions and collect them at the end of the import, you can use the `Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsErrors` trait

```
    <?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\Failure;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Importable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsOnError;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\SkipsErrors;

class UsersImport implements ToModel, WithValidation, SkipsOnError
{
    use Importable, SkipsErrors;
}
```

For further Information read [This](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#skipping-errors)